# How to find the main function's entry point of elf executable file without any symbolic information?

Tags: linux, reverse, elf

I developed a small cpp program on platform of Ubuntu-Linux 11.10.
Now I want to reverse engineer it. I am beginner. *I use such tools: GDB 7.0, hte editor, hexeditor*.

For the first time I made it pretty easy. With help of symbolic information I founded the address of main function and made everything I needed.
Then I striped (`--strip-all`) executable elf-file and I have some problems. 
I know that `main` function starts from 0x8960 in this program.
But I haven't any idea how should I find this point without this knowledge.
I tried debug my program step by step with gdb but it goes into  `__libc_start_main`
then into the `ld-linux.so.3` (so, it finds and loads the shared libraries needed by a program). I debugged it about 10 minutes. Of course, may be in 20 minutes I can reach the main function's entry point, but, it seems, that more easy way has to exist.

What should I do to find the `main` function's entry point without any symbolic info?
Could you advise me some good books/sites/other_sources from reverse engineering of elf-files with help of gdb?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (ld-linux.so isn't the kernel, it's the dynamic linker, in user-space.)

Comment: Mat, Ok, I don't mind, but the question is the same.

Comment: I think glibc on x86 pushes `main()`'s address before calling `__libc_start_main` on `_start`. At least it did not long ago.

Comment: Yes, you are quite right! I have already found it yesterday in such way. :)

Answer (score 18):

Locating `main()` in a stripped Linux ELF binary is straightforward. No symbol information is required.

The prototype for [`__libc_start_main`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_2.0.1/LSB-Core/LSB-Core/baselib---libc-start-main-.html) is

```
int __libc_start_main(int (*main) (int, char**, char**), 
                      int argc, 
                      char *__unbounded *__unbounded ubp_av, 
                      void (*init) (void), 
                      void (*fini) (void), 
                      void (*rtld_fini) (void), 
                      void (*__unbounded stack_end));
```

The runtime memory address of `main()` is the argument corresponding to the first parameter, `int (*main) (int, char**, char**)`. This means that the last memory address saved on the runtime stack prior to calling `__libc_start_main` is the memory address of `main()`, since arguments are pushed onto the runtime stack in the reverse order of their corresponding parameters in the function definition.

One can enter `main()` in `gdb` in 4 steps:

1. Find the program entry point
2. Find where `__libc_start_main` is called
3. Set a break point to the address last saved on stack prior to the call to `_libc_start_main`
4. Let program execution `continue` until the break point for `main()` is hit

The process is the same for both 32-bit and 64-bit ELF binaries.

**Entering `main()` in an example stripped 32-bit ELF binary called "test_32":**

```
$ gdb -q -nh test_32
Reading symbols from test_32...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) info file                                  #step 1
Symbols from "/home/c/test_32".
Local exec file:
    `/home/c/test_32', file type elf32-i386.
    Entry point: 0x8048310
    < output snipped >
(gdb) break *0x8048310
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048310
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/c/test_32 

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048310 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/13i $eip                                 #step 2
=> 0x8048310:   xor    %ebp,%ebp
   0x8048312:   pop    %esi
   0x8048313:   mov    %esp,%ecx
   0x8048315:   and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x8048318:   push   %eax
   0x8048319:   push   %esp
   0x804831a:   push   %edx
   0x804831b:   push   $0x80484a0
   0x8048320:   push   $0x8048440
   0x8048325:   push   %ecx
   0x8048326:   push   %esi
   0x8048327:   push   $0x804840b                # address of main()
   0x804832c:   call   0x80482f0 <__libc_start_main@plt>
(gdb) break *0x804840b                           # step 3
Breakpoint 2 at 0x804840b
(gdb) continue                                   # step 4 
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x0804840b in ?? ()                # now in main()
(gdb) x/x $esp+4
0xffffd110: 0x00000001                           # argc = 1
(gdb) x/s **(char ***) ($esp+8)
0xffffd35c: "/home/c/test_32"                    # argv[0]
(gdb)
```

**Entering `main()` in an example stripped 64-bit ELF binary called "test_64":**

```
$ gdb -q -nh test_64
Reading symbols from test_64...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) info file                                  # step 1
Symbols from "/home/c/test_64".
Local exec file:
    `/home/c/test_64', file type elf64-x86-64.
    Entry point: 0x400430
    < output snipped >
(gdb) break *0x400430
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400430
(gdb) run 
Starting program: /home/c/test_64 

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400430 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/11i $rip                                 # step 2
=> 0x400430:    xor    %ebp,%ebp
   0x400432:    mov    %rdx,%r9
   0x400435:    pop    %rsi
   0x400436:    mov    %rsp,%rdx
   0x400439:    and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
   0x40043d:    push   %rax
   0x40043e:    push   %rsp
   0x40043f:    mov    $0x4005c0,%r8
   0x400446:    mov    $0x400550,%rcx
   0x40044d:    mov    $0x400526,%rdi            # address of main()
   0x400454:    callq  0x400410 <__libc_start_main@plt>
(gdb) break *0x400526                            # step 3
Breakpoint 2 at 0x400526
(gdb) continue                                   # step 4
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x0000000000400526 in ?? ()        # now in main()
(gdb) print $rdi                                    
$3 = 1                                           # argc = 1
(gdb) x/s **(char ***) ($rsp+16)
0x7fffffffe35c: "/home/c/test_64"                # argv[0]
(gdb)
```

A detailed treatment of program initialization and what occurs before `main()` is called and how to get to `main()` can be found be found in Patrick Horgan's tutorial ["Linux x86 Program Start Up
or - How the heck do we get to main()?"](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html)

Answer (score 17):

If you have a very stripped version, or even a binary that is packed, as using UPX, you can gdb on it in the tough way as:

```
$ readelf -h echo | grep Entry
Entry point address:               0x103120
```

And then you can break at it in GDB as:

```
$ gdb mybinary
(gdb) break * 0x103120
Breakpoint 1 at 0x103120gdb) 
(gdb) r
Starting program: mybinary 
Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000103120 in ?? ()
```

and then, you can see the entry instructions:

```
(gdb) x/10i 0x0000000000103120
=> 0x103120:    bl      0x103394
  0x103124: dcbtst  0,r5
  0x103128: mflr    r13
  0x10312c: cmplwi  r7,2
  0x103130: bne     0x103214
  0x103134: stw     r5,0(r6)
  0x103138: add     r4,r4,r3
  0x10313c: lis     r0,-32768
  0x103140: lis     r9,-32768
  0x103144: addi    r3,r3,-1
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I would consider this is the only correct answer. All other answers are C specific (and even specific to the compiler/libc implementation) but this answers the actual question reliably as it is asked (entry point of a Linux ELF executable).

Comment: Setting breakpoint won't work for crosscompiled binaries, but you can use `disassemble 0x103120` in that case.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, once a program has been stripped, there is no straightforward way to locate the function that the symbol `main` would have otherwise referenced.

The value of the symbol `main` is not required for program start-up: in the ELF format, the start of the program is specified by the `e_entry` field of the ELF executable header.  This field normally points to the C library's initialization code, and not directly to `main`.

While the C library's initialization code does call `main()` after it has set up the C run time environment, this call is a normal function call that gets fully resolved at link time.

In some cases, implementation-specific heuristics (i.e., the specific knowledge of the internals of the C runtime) could be used to determine the location of `main` in a stripped executable.  However, I am not aware of a portable way to do so.